# capturing complex names

Tags: regex, r

my data:

```
Caterina Guonçallvez braçeyro 
Francisco Ro[dr]í[gueJz luveyro
Johao de Miranda calçeteyro 
Lucas Martinz Mal-Cuzinhado, braçeyro 
Francisquo d[e] Arruda braçeyro 
Francisquo de Miranda braçeyro
```

-first name last name
-first name last name with brakets and J (brakets ocr recognition)
-first name last name with hyphen
-first name last name with particle
-first name last name with particle with brakets

Expected output

```
Caterina Guonçallvez
Francisco Ro[dr]í[gueJz
Johao de Miranda
Lucas Martinz Mal-Cuzinhado
Francisquo d[e] Arruda
Francisquo de Miranda
```

- Names are begining with uppercases
- The last  part of the name is followed by a space (or comma with space) and a word beginning with a lowercase character like "braçeyro" or  "calçeteyro" (people's jobs)

  data <- readLines("clipboard" , encoding = "latin1")

What I tried:

```
^([a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð])\w+[A-Z ,.'-]\w+
```

giving
Antonio Guomez
Caterina Guon
Francisco Ro
Johao de
Francisquo d

Comment: Can you paste expected output? As I don't know what's last name there.  We have simple last name around here in India.

Comment: I'd use `str_extract(s, "\\p{Lu}[\\w\\]\\[-]*(?:(?:\\s+d\\[?e\\]?)?\\s+\\p{Lu}[\\w\\]\\[-]*)*")`, it is a linear version of the accepted answer (thus is faster) and also matches names starting with any uppercase letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern `(([A-Z][\w\[\]-]+|de|d\[e\])\s?)+` returns:

```
'Caterina Guonçallvez '
'Francisco Ro[dr]í[gueJz '
'Johao de Miranda '
'Lucas Martinz Mal-Cuzinhado'
'Francisquo d[e] Arruda '
'Francisquo de Miranda '
```

This assumes you set your locale correctly.

The regex matches groups of letters (and hyphens), starting with an uppercase one, or "de", followed by an optional space. This means that you will need to strip the strings to remove trailing spaces.

---

**edit:** Proof it works in R:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","en_us.UTF-8")
> library(stringr)
> x <- "Caterina Guonçallvez braçeyro "
> str_match(x, '(([A-Z][\\w\\[\\]-]+|de|d\\[e\\])\\s?)+')
     [,1]                    [,2]           [,3]         
[1,] "Caterina Guonçallvez " "Guonçallvez " "Guonçallvez"
```

Comment: Ok, great!  `Francisco Ro[dr]í[gueJz luveyro`how include diachritics sign and accents?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to include the brackets in the character set. The accents should work automatically, if you have the right locale set, from the way I understood it. Unfortunately I misread your question and didn't see the `r` tag, so I made it in Python (where there's a simple flag `re.UNICODE`), but according to [this](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/regex.html) it should work if you have the right locale.

Comment: I use regexR to test the pattern. Not fully works in R

Comment: @Wilcar I tested it in R and it seemed to work, once I set the locale. See edit.

Comment: I am a little lost because in R I think I need to use two \\ for escape characters instead

Comment: If the first uppercase letter can have accents, or other than from ASCII Latin uppercase letters, replace `[A-Z]` with `\\p{Lu}`